Partial (basic) migration to new mac
When new hardware arrives is there a way to migrate just a portion of data? exclude 3rd party apps and kernel extensions installed on the mac being migrated. I have some remnants of cisco vpn that I have resting dormant on the outgoing mac that I don't want to be available on new mac. That and utorrent, etc.
Thanks!

So don't do a migrate.
Install a fresh system as part of a new Mac install.
Then bring across the data you wish from a backup.

AFAIR you can deselect the migration of all 3rd party applications in Migration Assistant.

@nohillside maybe, but I find that method works well, at least for me.

Gotta configure timemachine then. How do I selectively pull stuff back from a backup?

Time Machine backups allow one to access folders based on what I call a timeline - each folder is represented with a date, so access the one with the updates you want or go to one prior for an earlier version.

the only things I really care about are mail account setup, keys in keychain, bookmarks in browser. The stuff that's time consuming to redo and tedious. The rest I can pull from git.
